# AWS EC2 NVMe disk resize udev rule

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, udev, nvme

I just started migration of AWS EC2 T2 to T3 instances. I want to create udev rule which detects disk resize.

I created new rule

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="change", ENV{RESIZE}=="1", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger -t udev-subsystem-nvme %k -  serial:$attr{serial} - resize:%E{RESIZE} - id_serial:%E{ID_SERIAL} - devname:%E{DEVNAME}"`
```

in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-disk.rules` hit `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` and watched changes in `udevadm monitor` and `/var/log/syslog`

That worked in T2 instance, but does not work in T3 instance.  So I tried many different options, see

```
SUBSYSTEM=="nvme",RUN+="/usr/bin/logger -t udev-subsystem-nvme %k -  serial:$attr{serial} - resize:%E{RESIZE} - id_serial:%E{ID_SERIAL} - devname:%E{DEVNAME}"

SUBSYSTEM=="block",RUN+="/usr/bin/logger -t udev-subsystem-block %k -  serial:$attr{serial} - resize:%E{RESIZE} - id_serial:%E{ID_SERIAL} - devname:%E{DEVNAME}"

KERNEL=="nvme*",RUN+="/usr/bin/logger -t udev-kernel0 %k -  serial:$attr{serial} - resize:%E{RESIZE} - id_serial:%E{ID_SERIAL} - devname:%E{DEVNAME}"

KERNEL=="nvme[0-9]*n[0-9]*",RUN+="/usr/bin/logger -t udev-kernel1 %k -  serial:$attr{serial} - resize:%E{RESIZE} - id_serial:%E{ID_SERIAL} - devname:%E{DEVNAME}"
```

but none of them works. I can detect event of new disk attached, but can't detect disk resize.

It was tried with latest **Ubuntu 18.04 AMI** and **latest Amazon AMI**.

Will be very grateful for any advice, because I am starting to be little desperate (:

Comment: Are T2 instances using SCSI or NVMe storage?

Comment: On T2 instances EBS volumes are not exposed as NVMe block devices, so I guess SCSI can be. You can see it as `/dev/xvd[a-f]`  On T3 you see EBS volumes as `/dev/nvme[0-26]n1`

Answer (score 2):

It is a verified kernel bug/feature. I consulted this with AWS support, they were able to replicate this on latest Ubuntu, RedHat, Amazon Linux 1 and Amazon Linux 2.

This udev rule should work - it detects new device, but it does not detect device change.

`KERNEL=="nvme[0-9]*n[0-9]*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ATTRS{model}=="Amazon Elastic Block Store",RUN+="<some_action>"`